# Dealing with Tables in Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium and Python to crawl a petrol/gas price website to scrape the best price on the front page, which Ive done, and then searching for a post/zip code "6076" and getting the best price for that area and surrounding suburbs.

This is where I'm stuck as it is returning a table  in HTML. Per my code below I have extracted some of the table rows however I just want the "today" price and the location of where to get it from the first row of the table.

{hills} {local} and {price} are variables saved for referencing into an automated SMS later.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
browser = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.fuelwatch.wa.gov.au/fuelwatch/pages/home.jspx');")
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#homepage\:j_idt84\:bestMetroPrices\:0\:j_idt96\:1\:bestMetroPrice')
print("Best Petrol Price in Perth today is:", elem.text)
price = elem.text
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchform\:product_label')
elem.click()
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchform\:product_1')
elem.click()
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchform\:location_input').send_keys("6076")
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchform\:search')
elem.click()
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
elem = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")
for value in elem:
    print("Best Petrol Price Kalamunda and surrounding areas today is:", value.text)
local = elem.text
elem = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#searchResultForm\:searchResultsTbl\:0\:tooltip-tradingName')
print("At:", elem.text)
hills = elem.text
import messagebird

client = messagebird.Client('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
message = client.message_create(
          '+61XXXXXXXXX',
          '+61XXXXXXXXX',
          f'User, the Best Petrol Price in Perth today is: {price} at CostCo Perth Airport. The best price in Kalamunda and surrounding areas is {local} at {hills}. ', #Message goes here 
          { 'reference' : 'Foobar' }
```

Comment: Error 404 No error posted.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first row details from the final page you may do this :

A `CSS_SELECTOR` would be :

```
tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-even[data-ri='0'] td

for details in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-even[data-ri='0'] td")
    print(details.text)
```

if you want to retrive 2nd row change `[data-ri='1']` and so on for any row.

Comment: Thanks for commenting - getting an invalid syntax error with that code. ```tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-even[data-ri='0'] td
                                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: ```elem = find_element_by_css_selector('tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-even[data-ri='0'] td')
print(elem.text)``` I varied between your code using ```for details in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-even[data-ri='0'] td")
    print(details.text)``` and using ```elem = find_element_by_css_selector('tr.ui-widget-content.ui-datatable-even[data-ri='0'] td')``` as this format worked for me consistently with the rest of the code, just gets stuck at this table.